# Passing 2 objects to a named route in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes, rspec-rails

In my RSpec test I do:
`delete recurring_events_path(@group, @recurring_event)`, but that yields `DELETE "/groups/705777939/recurring_events.496`

How should I craft the arguments to `recurring_events_path` so that it yields `/groups/705777939/recurring_events/496`?

**routes.rb**

```
 45   resources :groups, except: %i[new edit]
 [snipp..]
 56   scope "groups/:group_id" do
 57     resources :posts, except: %i[new edit]
 58     put "posts/:id/pin", to: "posts#pin"
 59
 60     resources :recurring_events, except: %i[show]
 61     get "recurring_events/upcoming" => "recurring_events#upcoming", as: :upcoming
 62     get "recurring_events/past" => "recurring_events#past", as: :past
 63
 64     scope "/posts/:post_id" do
 65       resources :comments, except: %i[new edit]
 66     end
 67   end
```

**$ rake routes**

```
recurring_events GET    /groups/:group_id/recurring_events(.:format)            recurring_events#index
                 POST   /groups/:group_id/recurring_events(.:format)            recurring_events#create
                 PATCH  /groups/:group_id/recurring_events/:id(.:format)        recurring_events#update
                 PUT    /groups/:group_id/recurring_events/:id(.:format)        recurring_events#update
                 DELETE /groups/:group_id/recurring_events/:id(.:format)        recurring_events#destroy
```

Comment: show your routes.rb, it looks like you didn't set the routes properly from your `rake routes` output (no name for the routes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your route to use nested resources like this:

```
 resources :groups, except: %i[new edit]
   resources :posts, except: %i[new edit]
     resources :comments, except: %i[new edit] #be careful with this, tree levels of nesting is not recommended, I would move this out of the "group" namespace
     member do
       put :pin
     end
   end

   resources :recurring_events, except: %i[show] do
     collection do
       get :upcoming
       get :past
     end
   end
 end
```

Now `rake routes` should give you all routes with it's names.

More info on the docs: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Answer (score 0):

`recurring_events_path` here stands for your `#index` route

If you're using `resource` in routes the path should be `destroy_recurring_events_path`. Otherwise, you need to specify `as:` option in the route declaration. Like `as: :destroy_recurring_events`

You can see aliases for routes using `rake routes` command

Comment: I've added the recurring_evnts parts of `rake routes` to my post. Doesn't ** recurring_events_path** work for all the functions listed, as longs as you provide the correct HTTP verb?

Comment: @martins, that works only when the URL is the same, it would work for `/groups/:group_id/recurring_events` GET and POST, but the other URL for PATCH, PUT and DELETE is different

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `recurring_event_path` as singular event instead of `recurring_events_path`